# Why do we need "./" in front of an excutable c++ file when we want to run it?

Tags: c++, command-line, cat

Assume I have an executable C++ program called `lencode`, and I want to run it by using UUOC. I can run it successfully with the following command:

`cat file.txt | ./lencode`

But now, because of some requirements, I want my command line in the format of this instead:

`cat file.txt | lencode`

I failed to run the program. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, there is no quotes, my mistake.

Comment: This is definitely not a C++ question. What is _an executable C++ program_?

Comment: Because that's the way Unix-based operating systems work. This question is more suitable for [su] or [unix.se], and has nothing to do with C++ (or programming) - it's a basic "How does my operating system work?* question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the `./` prefix is because the current directory (as referred to by the shortcut `"."`) is not in your `$PATH` environment variable.

One answer is, put `"."` in your `$PATH` environment.

For bash:

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

For tcsh:

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:.
```

To determine your shell:

```
echo $0
```

For more information on your shell:

```
man bash
```

or

```
man tcsh
```

However this is a security risk. A better way to do it (as noted in Justin Rameriz's answer) is to put the directory that contains lencode (`/home/user/` if `lencode` is located at `/home/user/lencode`) in your `$PATH`, or move `lencode` to a directory that is in your `$PATH`.

For example, if you are using `tcsh` as your shell:

```
mkdir $HOME/bin
cp lencode $HOME/bin
setenv PATH ${PATH}:$HOME/bin
```

To keep this setting the next time you login, you should place this in your `$HOME/.tcshrc` file:

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:$HOME/bin
```

Comment: Putting "." in your PATH environment variable is a security risk.
See here for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come

Answer (score 1):

Add the directory of lencode to your path, or move it to a directory that is in your path. You may not always want the current directory in your path. i.e any time you have a file in your cwd that happens to be the name of a command.